# Storyboard changing Target WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, storyboard

What do I have to change from the following code to make the Storyboard work with an image within a List<> instead of making it work with an ellipse?

```xml
<Storyboard x:Name="sbMoveImages">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-1"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="641"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:5" Value="640"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:5" Value="160"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.Rotation)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:5" Value="359.82"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just changing the `Storyboard.TargetName` should be enough.

Comment: I tried doing that but i'm not sure how to do it syntactically. Can you please elaborate? Possibly provide a code snippet? Thank you.

Comment: That's not how it works. You show what you've tried and the specific issue you're having. A complete, minimal, repro may also help people to help you.